# Exponential Growth problem with a twist.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been searching for a solution to the following problem(s) for quite some time.  The answer is uncomplicated in nature, but I haven't been able to get far without bruteforcing it.  Can anyone assist me?  Here's the problem:

1. A female rabbit reaches sexual maturity between 3 and 6 months old. The litter size is between 4 and 12 rabbits. The gestationn period is between 28 and 31 days. Create a model to predict rabbit population after 5 years if the initial population contains 1 female and 1 male. Assume 0 mortality."
2. Falcons are introduced into the ecosystem one year after the male and female rabbits began producing. Falcons consume 15% of the rabbit population every month. Create a model of this after 4 years.

As I said, I've bruteforced it (actually written down the months, adding the doubling of the years, etc.)  It feels like a recursive sequence wrapped up in a nasty exponential growth pattern; it doesn't "feel" like the regular exponential growth problems I've dealt with before.  I'd appreciate it if anyone can assist me!  Thanks.

Comment: We can also assume that the litter size is 12, and that 6 males and 6 females are produced in every litter size.  We can also assume it takes 6 months for sexual maturity.  Maybe that will simplify things more.